# AlarmManager.setExact is not waiting the time interval

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have the following line

```
alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10000,pintent);
```

from what I understand I should receive a call from the AlarmManager to my Broadcast Receiver's onReceive after 10 seconds. How ever my Logs show that it reaches the onReceive method immediately. Is this normal? what method is triggered after the time specified in the setExact method above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line

```
alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,10000,pintent);
```

into

```
alarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+10000,pintent);
```

so it will reach after 10 seconds

**EDIT:**

From docs [setExact()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) will drain battery more..try to use `set()`

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pintent);
```

Comment: I tried this and Im no longer getting any thing back in the logs. I did not see in the references if the time parameter is milliseconds from current time or total current milliseconds + my time. Any idea why I wouldn't be seeing my log messages now?

Comment: @Mintybacon time paramanter is from the current time only..otherwise it will fire immediately if the given time is past time..

Comment: I got it working! this helped along with changing the id in getbroadcast from 0. Thanks!

Comment: I spent way too much time on this problem. This saved me. Thanks